# Telethon GetLocatedRequest: How do you access the user_id and distance information?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I've been reading the Telethon docs all week, in addition to scouring the internet, and I can't find the answer to this.

I've done a GetLocatedRequest and successfully received the data, but I can't figure out how to access the user_id and distance information to use in the rest of my script.  Is there a specific object to call in order to grab this data?  My only work around so far has been to copy paste the output to a .txt file and manually parse, which is pretty awful.

My code is below.  point0 is the point I'm locating from, and I'd like to get the user_id and distance in the user variable.  So far I've tried things like user.peer, user.PeerLocated, user.user_id, but none of them work.  Anybody run into this before?  Here's what the GetLocatedRequest outputs:

Updates(updates=[UpdatePeerLocated(peers=[PeerLocated(peer=PeerUser(user_id=xxxxxx), expires=datetime.datetime(2038, 1, 19, 3, 14, 7, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), distance=100), PeerLocated(peer=PeerUser(user_id=xxxxxxx), expires=datetime.datetime(2038, 1, 19, 3, 14, 7, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), distance=100),

```
from pprint import pprint
import re
import csv
import pandas as pd
import asyncio
import nest_asyncio
import configparser
import time
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.errors import SessionPasswordNeededError
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetHistoryRequest
from telethon import functions, types
from telethon import errors
from telethon.tl.types import PeerLocated, PeerUser
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty
from telethon.tl.types import PeerChannel, InputPeerChannel

nest_asyncio.apply()


# Reading Configs
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")

# Setting configuration values
api_id = config['Telegram']['api_id']
api_hash = config['Telegram']['api_hash']
api_hash = str(api_hash)
phone = config['Telegram']['phone']
username = config['Telegram']['username']

client = TelegramClient("tes", api_id, api_hash)

async def loc0():
    await client.start()
    print('client starting')
    await client.get_me()
    print('complete')
    point0 = await client(functions.contacts.GetLocatedRequest(
        geo_point=types.InputGeoPoint(lat=41.1, long=69.0)))
    user = point0.PeerLocated
    print(user)
    print('\n point0 \n {}'.format(point0.stringify()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code returns a list of users not only 1 user. to access them you need to use list indexing.

```
users = point0.updates[0].peers
for user in users:
    print(user.peer.user_id)
```

Comment: Worked like a champ, thanks for the help.  Ended up having to add a try/except block to handle the difference between the peerUser and PeerChannel objects returned by GetLocatedRequest.  Thanks